# Invalid operands to binary when I try to multiply elemets from two matrices

Tags: c, matrix

In a method I have a **m*n** matrix and an array (allocated as a **m*1** matrix), unfortunately during compilation I get this error:

```
main.c:337:30: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘float’ and ‘float *’)
                 yp += matrixA[i][j] * listB[j];
```

the full code of the method is this

```
float error(float **matrixA, float **listB, int m, int n) {
    int i, j;
    float err = 0, de, yp;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        yp = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            yp += matrixA[i][j] * listB[j];
        de = fabs(matrixA[i][j]-yp);
        err += (de*de);
    }
    return err;
}
```

Both **matrixA** and **listB** use the same allocation method.

Why this error?
How should I fix?

Comment: `matrixA[i][j] * listB[j]` look at: `float **matrixA, float **listB` and `(have ‘float’ and ‘float *’)` it really says it all...

Comment: `listB[j]` type is `float*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listB[j]` is of `float *` type. You are multiplying it with `float` type. Change

```
yp += matrixA[i][j] * listB[j];
```

to

```
yp += matrixA[i][j] * listB[j][i];
```